# Freemium video game data for churn analysis

Tags: games

I'm looking for video game player analytics data, ideally from a game with the "Freemium" payment model, in order to predict player churn. This analysis would benefit from features such as:

- Date of signup
- Individual records for each game session along with date/time and player ID
- Playtime per session
- Purchases made (if any)

Any additional details regarding the in-game actions would be a bonus and likely improve the analysis.